# Text is faded when using positioning

Tags: css, text, positioning

UPDATE: This problem only occurs in safari on a mac computer.

[image: Left: safari Right: google chrome]
Left: safari Right: google chrome

I have a header positioned on top of a slideshow, and any text is faded in colour. When the page loads it starts off white and then immediately fades. I have put the site up temporarily at [actorscms.co.uk](http://www.actorscms.co.uk)
You can see the email and phone number in the top right is faded. Text that is placed anywhere on the slideshow (not just the top area) becomes faded.

HTML

```
<div id="bannerbox">
<div id="banner">
//slideshow//
</div>
</div>


<div id="headerbox">
<div id="header">
<div id="social">
<img src="../images/fb thumb.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Facebook" />
<img src="../images/twitter thumb.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Twitter" /><br />
Email: <a href="mailto:info@blubuddha.co.uk ">info@blubuddha.co.uk </a><br />
    Phone: xxxxxxxxxxx
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a class="home" href="index.html"></a></li>
<li><a class="services" href="services.html"></a></li>
<li><a class="prices" href="prices.html"></a></li>
<li><a class="contact" href="contacts.html"></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bannerbox {
position:relative;
width:100%;
padding-bottom:20px;
border-top:1px solid #191919;
background-color:#000;
} 

#banner {
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#headerbox {
width:100%;
height:120px;
position:absolute;
background-image:url(../images/black.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
z-index:1;
top:0;
}

#header {
height: 120px;
min-width: 980px;
max-width:1100px;
background-image: url(../images/header.png);
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
font-size:20px;
color:#bfefff;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;   
}

#social {
float:right;
text-align:right;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:15px;
line-height:20px;
font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
color:#fff;
font-size:15px;
}

#navigation
{
height:50px;
padding-top:67px;
margin-left:142px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! This problem is caused by the soundcloud iframe. Once I deleted that everything was fine!

Answer (score 0):

Its not faded you just set the font color to gray.

```
#social {
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:15px;
    line-height:20px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    color:#FFF!important; CHANGE HERE TO MAKE IT WHITE
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Comment: no even if it is set to white it is still faded. I will update the site to show you. And look at the big header, that is also set to white.

Comment: @KieranVyas then change it to color:#FFF!important;

Comment: @KieranVyas Looks fine to me on the site now

Comment: I think what's tricking my eye is the fact that when I load the page it starts off white, and then immediately fades. Does this not happen on your browser? I'm using safari

Comment: @KieranVyas Im using Chrome I dont think that would be a huge problem thought this is fairly straightforward. Try doing a hard reload and clearing your cache and everything. I also just pulled it up on my iPad (only safari I have) and its still white

Comment: Yep cleared everything, no change. It's not a huge problem but it's just very distracting when you load the page on safari. I just checked it on chrome and the slideshow is not showing up? This could possibly be the problem! Can you see the slideshow?

Comment: @KieranVyas I do see the slideshow in chrome. I dont know what your problem could be make sure everything is up to date I guess. It looks fine on all my devices.

Comment: checked it on multiple devices and it's fine on all except safari on a mac. How strange!

Comment: I have uploaded a picture to demonstrate the difference between safari and chrome

Comment: @KieranVyas Theres no way for me to help you. Use safari's developer tools and find the CSS property that is setting the font color. Or overriding the one being set.

Comment: @KieranVyas Here is a long shot though. give social a `z-index:10` and see if somehow that mask if over laying it although I dont think that is the problem

Comment: no that didn't work unfortunately! it is definitely something to do with the z-index and positioning though. Once you remove those attributes it removes the problem. I just can't find a way to make it work

Comment: fixed! It was being corrupted somehow by the sound cloud iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The `color` for #social is set to #aaa, which is why it looks faded.  Set it to #FFF.

Comment: I have changed the colour to #FFF and it is still faded. In safari, when the page loads the text actually starts white and then fades immediately.

Comment: As Kierchon said, add `!important`.  It looks white to me now, though.  Refresh the page, perhaps your CSS is cached.